# Spark: optimise writing a DataFrame to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, scala, apache-spark

I am using the code below to write a DataFrame of 43 columns and about 2,000,000 rows into a table in SQL Server:

```
dataFrame
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", tablename)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .save()
```

Sadly, while it does work for small DataFrames it's either extremely slow or gets timed out for large ones. Any hints on how to optimize it?

I've tried setting `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Thanks.

Comment: There are huge columns (MEDIUMTEXTs, LONGTEXTs, BLOBs, ...) on your rows? Try to see in your databases how many queries are executing in parallel at moment of write command (SHOW PROCESSLIST sql command). Maybe it can give you some trace of what is wrong

Comment: @Dawid did you finally find an approach using PySpark ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We resorted to using the [azure-sqldb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) library instead of the default built-in exporting functionality of Spark. This library gives you a `bulkCopyToSqlDB` method which is a *real* batch insert and goes *a lot* faster. It's a bit less practical to use than the built-in functionality, but in my experience it's still worth it.

We use it more or less like this:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.query._

val options = Map(
  "url"          -> "***",
  "databaseName" -> "***",
  "user"         -> "***",
  "password"     -> "***",
  "driver"       -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
)

// first make sure the table exists, with the correct column types
// and is properly cleaned up if necessary
val query = dropAndCreateQuery(df, "myTable")
val createConfig = Config(options ++ Map("QueryCustom" -> query))
spark.sqlContext.sqlDBQuery(createConfig)

val bulkConfig = Config(options ++ Map(
  "dbTable"           -> "myTable",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "20000",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkConfig)
```

As you can see we generate the `CREATE TABLE` query ourselves. You *can* let the library create the table, but it will just do `dataFrame.limit(0).write.sqlDB(config)` which can still be pretty inefficient, probably requires you to cache your `DataFrame`, and it doesn't allow you to choose the `SaveMode`.

Also potentially interesting: we had to use an `ExclusionRule` when adding this library to our sbt build, or the `assembly` task would fail.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-sqldb-spark" % "1.0.2" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark")
)
```

Comment: Hi guys, I am using pyspark and the jdbc driver is becoming a bottleneck. Any suggestion to improve performance in the mentioned scenario?

Comment: @FelipePerezR did you find an alternative ?

Comment: Try this out https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark

Comment: Will it work with MSSQL 2019 as well ?

Answer (score 14):

Try adding **`batchsize`** option to your statement with atleast `> 10000`(change this value accordingly to get better performance)  and execute the write again.

[From spark docs:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

> The JDBC batch size, which determines **how many rows to insert per
>   round trip**. This can help performance on JDBC drivers. This option
>   applies only to writing. It **defaults to 1000**.

**Also its worth to check out:**

- **`numPartitions`** `option` to increase the parallelism (This also determines the maximum number of concurrent JDBC connections)
- **`queryTimeout`** `option` to increase the timeouts for the write option.

Comment: Thanks. Playing with the batch size allows to get about a million records through. Still getting the following error for larger ones though: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.

Comment: @Dawid,did you tried with **`queryTimeout`** option also?, `(or)` try adding `keep alive/querytimeout`** parameters to your jdbc url `(or)` asking sql server admins to increase the **`timeouts`** as per your query time..!!

Comment: @Shu the link you have shared is down

Answer (score 2):

In order improve the performance using **PY-Spark** (due to Administrative restrictions to use python, SQL and R only) one can use below options.

#### Method 1: Using JDBC Connector

This method reads or writes the data **row by row**, resulting in performance issues. **Not Recommended**.

```
df.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.mode("overwrite or append") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("dbtable", table_name) \
.option("user", username) \
.option("password", password) \
.save()
```

#### Method 2: Using Apache Spark connector (SQL Server & Azure SQL)

This method uses bulk insert to read/write data. There are a lot more options that can be further explored.

First Install the Library using **Maven Coordinate** in the Data-bricks cluster, and then use the below code.

**Recommended for Azure SQL DB or Sql Server Instance**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15

```
df.write \
.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
.mode("overwrite or append") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("dbtable", table_name) \
.option("user", username) \
.option("password", password) \
.option("batchsize", as per need) \
.option("mssqlIsolationLevel", "READ_UNCOMMITTED")\
.save()
```

#### Method 3: Using Connector for Azure Dedicated SQL Pool (formerly SQL DW)

This method previously uses **Poly-base** to read and write data to and from Azure Synapse using a staging server (mainly, blob storage or a Data Lake storage directory), but now data are being read and write using **Copy**, as the `Copy` method has improved performance.

**Recommended for Azure Synapse**

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html

```
df.write \
.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
.option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
.option("dbTable", "<your-table-name>") \
.option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
.save()
```

Comment: Do you have a instruction on how to get `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark` jar working in AWS Glue?

Answer (score 1):

is converting data to CSV files and copying those CSV's is an option for you?
we have automated this process for bigger tables and transferring those in GCP in CSV format. rather than reading this through JDBC.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [sql-spark connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector)

```
df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
```

More info also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15)