# Very, very slow write from dataframe to SQL Server table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm running the code below and it works fine, but it's supper, super, super slow.

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name', 
                             dbtable='dbo.my_table', 
                             user='usr', 
                             password='pwd', 
                             batchsize=500000).mode('append').save()
```

I thought it would load records in batches of 500k at a time, but when I run the code and do record counts in SQL Server after the job kicks off, it's updating about 50 records per second.  Hopefully there is an easy fix for this.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @HSA I'm also using spark JDBC 
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(....)
I'm reading from Kafka in 5 min batch interval and saving to Vertica DB.
Amount of data is 40M and more per hour, topic has data in 10K rate per second.
What spark Versio r u using? ( I'm 2.1.1) and spark configuration?
Can u paste from web UI the relevant details?

Comment: I'm seeing this: Spark Version:latest-stable-scala2.11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: optimise writing a DataFrame to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708079/spark-optimise-writing-a-dataframe-to-sql-server)

Comment: Well, that's Scala.  I only have access to Python and SQL in my current environment.  I ran this exact code a couple months ago, and the results were awesome.  We changed things in our environment recently.  Now, I only have access to Python and SQL.

Comment: What changed exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Check if `read` method is configured with below params.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

```
spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    #...
    .option("partitionColumn", "partition_key") \
    .option("lowerBound", "<lb>") \
    .option("upperBound", "<ub>") \
    .option("numPartitions", "<np>") \
    .option("fetchsize", "<fs>")
```